# My published app not showing on Google Play Store

Tags: android

I'd unpublished and release a new version and then published again on play store.

Now it's showing published in Play store console. But not still not showing on Play store.

Can anyone suggest to me? I need every opinion and suggestions from everyone.

Thank You all.

Comment: You mean when you are searching it's not showing?
In play console on right top click on the see on play store there you can see your app on play store.

Comment: This is not the right place to ask this question. If you have any programming related question ask here.

Answer (score 1):

If the app is showing published status in google play console, then wait for some time it takes time to list app on the search list in play store. It may take s some hours to day.

But you can see your app when you went through the publisher link of the app,

Comment: Thanks!
But I unpublished and republished my app after an update released.
I can't find via link that play store direct.
Any opinion Sir? It's deadly important for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with clear cache and data of google play app. As per google's "If you’ve submitted an update that hasn’t showed up on Google Play, please wait at least 24 hours before contacting our support team."

checkout here:- https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en&ref_topic=7072031

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but fixed it with this steps.
On your

> Developer console,

> select your app,
> then
> App Bundle Explorer.

You'll see the

> Details

provided by play store. Make sure the Permissions, Features, Screen Layouts, API levels, Target SDK, OpenGL ES versions, OpenGL textures match those in your AndroidManifest.xml file in your app.

The Google Play Filter might be hiding your application due to this reason.

For more information on this, head here:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/filters

Hope this is helpful.

This is an example of my manifest file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="io.bojack.meta">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.faketouch" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait"/>
    <uses-feature android:openGlEsVersion="0.0+" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" />
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
        
        
......
```